# How to perform a monkey test (step by step)?

Tags: asp.net, monkey-testing

What is monkey test and what do I have to do to have my web application (ASP.Net) tested by it.
Was looking around, but did not find anything precise I could base on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/marmelab/gremlins.js)

1. Download a file called: gremlins.min.js
2. In you page, on script part:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  gremlins.createHorde().unleash(); 
});
```

DONE!